# What is the difference between Widget sample and Widget *get* sample?

Tags: dart, flutter

beginner in Flutter here,

Does anybody know the difference, or significance of the keyword get in the context of instantiating a widget?

I'm declaring a widget here

```
ListTile sampleListTile {
  return ListTile(...);
}
```

In this scenario, I'm getting an error of *Methods must have an explicit list of parameters.*, to be solved by coding it as a method by adding () to the widgetname.

But here,

```
ListTile get sampleListTile {
  return ListTile(...);
}
```

Everything works out alright... I tried searching around but I can't nail down the relevant article.

Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first syntax is an "instance method", so the syntax should be (note the extra `()`):

```
ListTile sampleListTile() {
  return ListTile(...);
}
```

which you call like:

```
ListTile foo = sampleListTile();
```

and can have parameters as necessary.

The second syntax is of a [getter](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters) which are special instance methods that have no parameters. They feel more like "instance variables" in that you use them like:

```
ListTile bar = sampleListTile;
```